# Nokogiri not parsing XML in ruby - xmlns issue?

Tags: ruby, xml, web-services, nokogiri

Given the following ruby code :

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ProgramList xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns='http://publisher.webservices.affili.net/'>
  <TotalRecords>145</TotalRecords>
  <Programs>
    <ProgramSummary>
      <ProgramID>6540</ProgramID>
      <Title>Matalan</Title>
      <Limitations>A bit of text
      </Limitations>
      <URL>http://www.matalan.co.uk</URL>
      <ScreenshotURL>http://www.matalan.co.uk/</ScreenshotURL>
      <LaunchDate>2009-11-02T00:00:00</LaunchDate>
      <Status>1</Status>
    </ProgramSummary>
    <ProgramSummary>
      <ProgramID>11787</ProgramID>
      <Title>Club 18-30</Title>
      <Limitations/>
      <URL>http://www.club18-30.com/</URL>
      <ScreenshotURL>http://www.club18-30.com</ScreenshotURL>
      <LaunchDate>2013-05-16T00:00:00</LaunchDate>
      <Status>1</Status>
    </ProgramSummary>
  </Programs>
</ProgramList>"

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
p doc.xpath("//Programs")
```

gives :

```
=> []
```

Not what is expected.

On further investigation if I remove `xmlns='http://publisher.webservices.affili.net/'` from the initial  `<ProgramList>` tag I get the expected output.

Indeed if I change `xmlns='http://publisher.webservices.affili.net/'` to `xmlns:anything='http://publisher.webservices.affili.net/'` I get the expected output.

So my question is what is going on here? Is this malformed XML? And what is the best strategy for dealing with it?

While it's hardcoded in this example the XML is (will be) coming from a web service.

#### Update

I realise I can use the `remove_namespaces!` method but the Nokogiri docs do say that it's `"...probably is not a good thing in general"` to do this. Also I'm interested in why it's happening and what the 'correct' XML should be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `xmlns='http://publisher.webservices.affili.net/'` indicates the [*default namespace*](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#defaulting) for all elements under the one where it appears (including the element itself). That means that all elements that don’t otherwise have an explicit namespace fall under this namespace.

XPath queries don’t have default namespaces (at least in XPath 1.0), so any name that appears in one without a prefix refers to that element in no namespace.

In your code, you want to find `Program` elements in the `http://publisher.webservices.affili.net/` namespace (since that is the default namespace), but are looking (in your XPath query) for `Program` elements in *no* namespace.

To explicitly [specify the namespace in the query](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html#namespaces), you can do something like this:

```
doc.xpath("//pub:Programs", "pub" => "http://publisher.webservices.affili.net/")
```

Nokogiri makes this a little easier for namespaces declared on the root element (as in this case), declaring them for you with the same prefix. It will also declare the default namespace using the `xmlns` prefix, so you can also do:

```
doc.xpath("//xmlns:Programs")
```

which will give you the same result.